# searching backwards with regex

Tags: regex, groovy

I have the following different texts

```
line1: SELECT column1,
line2: column2,
line3: RTRIM(LTRIM(blah1)) || ' ' || RTRIM(LTRIM(blah3)),
line4: RTRIM(LTRIM(blah3)) || ' ' || RTRIM(LTRIM(some1)) outColumn,
line5: RTRIM(LTRIM(blah3)) || ' ' || RTRIM(LTRIM(some1)) something,
line6: somelast
```

Following is what I want to get out of each line
basically want to start the regex search from end of string and keep going untill space. I can take out comma later on.

```
line1: column1
line2: column2
line3: <space> nothing found
line4: outColumn
line5: something
line6: somelast
```

basically I will be fine if I can start the regex from the end and walk towards first space.

There probably will have to be a special case for line3 as I dont expect anything back.

I am using groovy for this regex.

Comment: Why is there a comma in the match 'outColumn,' but not in 'column1' and 'column2'?

Comment: your results don't really tell anything, unless you are looking for the words with "column" in them.

Comment: @bart sorry that was a typo. fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
(\w*)\s*,?$
```

Where match group one contains the first word at the end of the line.

Anchoring the expression to the end of the line basically *is* starting the regex from the end.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the lines and match each line against the regex:

```
(?i).*(column\w+).*
```

The word you're looking for is captured in group 1 ($1).

Comment: hmm I want to capture anyword...not just starting with 'column'.  but I see the example was a bit misleading...